# React-Native Redux Functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux so I would like to know if redux would be useful in a small e-commerce app with firebase? When I say small I mean like 4 screens.(Account, Shop, Product Index, Mini Game).

Comment: When working with small application using 4-5 screens and making use of real time database like firebase is a good way to start you web application. Also react frontend with redux will work absolutely fine with this web application of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with `react`, if you configure `redux` it mainly becomes helpful in the following scenarios.

1. When you have to **pass data between screens** that have **no navigation to each 
   other**.
2. When have to change something for example change a map theme in a screen when
   theme is changed from settings page.The screen and settings page is completely 
   **different levels at stack and have no relation**.You can achieve this using 
   redux.
3. The above two requirements are achieved so that a **reducer of a redux component 
   can be accessed from any other component**(you will if you have understood 
   redux).This makes it possible that once a **`API` is loaded in a screen the data 
   can be fed to any other screen spontaneously**.
4. Whatever happens in redux, **happens instantly there no delay just because redux 
   is there**.

These are the main few **merits i noted during my work experience** hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/why-use-redux-reasons-with-clear-examples-d21bffd5835)

> Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript applications. It helps you write applications that behave consistently, run in different environments (client, server, and native), and are easy to test. — https://redux.js.org/

It really doesn't matter how many screens your apps have, as long as you want a applications that behave consistently, it's advisable to use `Redux`